# Retrieving data from the same database with the Identity

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I connected the identity model of my WebApp to my MySQL Database, and modified it like I want to connect.

My question is the next: If I want to get data from tables not used in the Identity but still from the same database, What is the correct way to do it? Should I open a new connection and get the data with a class? Is there a way to implement it in the model?

I attach the code to connect to the database:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration());
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    context = new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

And my connectionStrings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=x.x.x.x;uid=user;password=pwd;database=db;port=3306;charset=utf8" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(Sorry if the question is too obvious, I'm starting to develop apps in ASP.NET MVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is open the connection when it is required. 
So, i assume you did something like this with your MySQL Database connections

```
public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
         if (!context.Database.Exists())
         {
          // if database did not exist before - create it
           context.Database.Create();
         }
         else
         {
          // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database 
           var migrationHistoryTableExists =        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
            string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
      "[Insert your database schema here - such as 'users']"));

    // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
          if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
          {
             context.Database.Delete();
             context.Database.Create();
          }
        }
   }}
```

and your ApplicationDbContext class will be like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser{}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   static ApplicationDbContext()
   {
       Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
   }

   public ApplicationDbContext()
  : base("DefaultConnection")
  {
  }
}
```

Now, to do some queries from database, you need to create an object of `ApplicationDbContext`

So, your Next Question "Is there a way to implement it in the model?" Yes there is you need to Create a View Model.

```
public class ItemProduct
{
    public int Id {get; set;};
    public string Name {get; set;};
}
```

So, lets say a Product Table exists in your database and we can query on it.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
   ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
  public ActionResult AnyName() 
  {
     List<ItemProduct> lstProducts = new List<ItemProduct>();
     var getProducts = (from p in context.Products
                        select p).ToList();
     foreach(var item in getProducts)
     {
         ItemProduct pro = new ItemProduct()
         {
            pro.Id = item.Id,
            pro.Name = item.Name
         };
         lstProducts.Add(pro);
     }

     // So, you have all your Products in ItemProduct Class list.
     // Now, return lstProducts to your View to show it on front end

  }
}
```

Hope this answer your question :)

Comment: I try it and I will let you know, but it looks like the next step. Can you explain me what `from p in context.Products select p` does? It selects all the table?

Comment: here **Products** is your Table Name from database. and it select all the columns from that table. You need to work on LINQ queries. Can you name any one table which you have in database with the column names. So, i can explain you better.

Comment: Ok, so that is a Linq query. I should work on them then, don't worry that's on my side. Thank you @Jawand Singh !